# gnome-calendar in xfce4: I cannot use google calendar

Tags: gnome, archlinux, xfce

I cannot configure online accounts with gnome-calendar in Xfce4 nop lxde. When I press in google line for example, it makes nothing. Is there something I missed?

[image]

I use Arch Linux.

Comment: I still have exactly the same problem with LinuxMint 18 Cinnamon...

Answer (score 2):

## Update: workaround

Launch GNOME Control Center with this trick (thanks, [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/7dcc0o/fix_for_blank_gnome_control_center_settings_with/)):

`env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center`

and set up your calendar settings (Online accounts) from there.

Worked for me :)

## Original "answer"

Not an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment :)

I use Arch Linux, too, with XFCE Desktop and I experience the same problem.

As I'm watching the output of `journalctl -f` while trying to add a new calendar provider, I get some clues on what is going on:

[image: experience]

I get similar errors if I'm trying to launch GNOME Control Center.

The function

`#4 0x00005654135cad52 cc_shell_model_set_panel_visibility (gnome-control-center)`

appears in both of the outputs.

My best guess is that to access these settings, the calendar app uses GNOME Control Center, but the latter assumes GNOME Shell and calls a function that depends on its runtime environment.

Comment: It does not work for me: I can edit my accounts in gnome-control but when I use gnome-calendar, I get "expired session"

Answer (score -1):

1 .Go to Google Calendar -> Settings (**Top Right of the page**)

2 .In there, click on the `Calendar Tab` (**Top left of said page**)

3 . Click on `export Calendar`. This will download the calendar in an `.ics` file format.

4 . Extract the `.ics` file and go to Gnome Calendar, click on settings. From the dialogue box that appears, select `from file` and go to the extracted `.ics` location and **select the one without the '#' in the starting of its name.**

5 . Select synchronize back in Calendar and make sure your internet is working.

Comment: I cannot use properly the interface. I have no problem with the format itself of the calendar

Comment: We know how to add an ics file. This does not answer the question and should be deleted.